# How do I retrieve then print the currently viewed sub categories?

Tags: posts, categories

I am building a 'course-like' WP site, without the use of any particular 'course plugins' and for this, I need to be able to show all the sub-categories in the sidebar for that particular course.

Example:
I have a course about cooking. Here are the Categories (parents in bold) and sub-categories (along with posts in Italics)...

**A Food Course** (Parent)
Preparing food (SubCat) - *Washing hands* - *Hair nets* - *What tools to use*
Using Ingredients (SubCat) - *Storage* - *Use-by Dates*

So, if the user is on a post page (say Hair Nets), then in the sidebar, I need to display the menu structure for that particular Parent Category, so they can skip to other sections just in that course, quickly.

I know, to generate the menu I would need to get/retrieve the parent category of the current post, can anyone shed any light?

Comment: And could extend your example and show, what exactly should be printed in sidebar in this case?